# how to REPL a quick javascript test

Tags: windows, node.js, module

I'm just starting out with node.js. I've built a module and I'm trying to run it quickly in REPL.

In my module I have this (excluding the guts here)

```
var templateModule = (function (templateModule) {

     //implimentation...

     // return module
     return templateModule;
})(templateModule || {});

 // do the export so node is happy
 module.exports.templateModule = templateModule;
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious. On **windows** I CD to c:/nodeCode/ and run node. 
Then in the node-REPL I type

> var temp = require('templateModule');

Result:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'templateModule'
       at Function.Module._resolveFilename ...
```

I also get this error if I do node test-server.js that contains a require.

Maybe I am missing some boilerplate? Maybe I need a package.json or something? The doc is confusing and I can't find a good REPL node.js hello world example for windows.

UPDATE:

It seems I can use modules fine in the browser using browserify... Is something maybe broken with my paths or my node installation?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a custom module, you have to do like this:

```
var temp = require('./templateModule');
```

or:

```
var temp = require('./templateModule.js');
```

, assuming your module file is called 'templateModule.js' and is in the same directory you are running de `node` command.

[This article](http://howtonode.org/creating-custom-modules) might help you.